# Issues inserting muliple MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to update a table of dishes with a new entry and cross reference it to an existing table of ingredients.  For each dish added, the user is required to assign existing ingredients and the volume required on multiple lines.  On submission, the Dish should be entered into the table 'Dishes' and the assigned ingredients should be entered into the 'DishIng' linked tabled.

My tables are set like this:

```
Table: "Dishes" Columns: DishID, DishName, Serves, etc...
Table: "DishIng" Columns: DishID, IngID, Volume
Table: "Ingredients" Columns: IngID, IngName, Packsize etc...
```

HTML:

```
<form action="Array.php" method="post">
<ul>
<li>DishID: <input type="text" name="DishID"></li>
<li>Name: <input type="text" name="DishName"></li>
<li>Catagory : <input type="text" name="DishCatID"></li>
<li>Serving: <input type="text" name="Serving"></li>
<li>SRP: <input type="text" name="SRP"></li>
<li>Method : <input type="text" name="Method"></li>
<li>Source : <input type="text" name="SourceID"></li>
<br>
<li>IngID: <input type="text" name="IngID"></li>
<li>Volume: <input type="text" name="Volume"></li>

<li>IngID: <input type="text" name="IngID"></li>
<li>Volume: <input type="text" name="Volume"></li>

<li>IngID: <input type="text" name="IngID"></li>
<li>Volume: <input type="text" name="Volume"></li>

</ul>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Any suggestions for dynamically adding a row of ingredients in HTML would be very welcome.

PHP:

```
<?php

require_once('db_connect.php');

$DishID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['DishID']);
$DishName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['DishName']);
$DishCatID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['DishCatID']);
$Serving = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Serving']);
$SRP = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['SRP']);
$Method = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Method']);
$SourceID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['SourceID']);
$IngID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['IngID']);
$Volume = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Volume']);

$array = array('$DishID', '$IngID', '$Volume');


$sql="INSERT INTO Dishes (DishID, DishName, DishCatID, Serving, SRP, Method, SourceID)
VALUES ('$DishID', '$DishName', '$DishCatID', '$Serving', '$SRP', '$Method', '$SourceID')";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO DishIng (DishID, IngID, Volume) VALUES ('$DishID', '$IngID', '$Volume')";

$it = new ArrayIterator ( $array );

$cit = new CachingIterator ( $it );

foreach ($cit as $value)
{
  $sql2 .= "('".$cit->key()."','" .$cit->current()."')";

    if( $cit->hasNext() )
    {
        $sql2 .= ",";
    }
}

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "records added";


require_once('db_disconnect.php');
php?>
```

Currently on submit, it only updates the 'Dishes' table and gives me this message: '1 record addedError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('0','$DishID'),('1','$IngID'),('2','$Volume')' at line 1'

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes. So `$array` contains the literal string `$DishID`, not the value of that variable. Why did you put it in quotes if you wanted to make an array of those values?

Comment: You have multiple fields in your form with the same name. Only one of them will be submitted. You should give them names ending in `[]`, then PHP will collect them into an array.

Comment: I'm really struggling to get this right, is the basis of my foreach statement correct, as others are picking up on that rather than the array element.  How would you suggest this was best written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your form to use array-style names for the repeated inputs:

```
<form action="Array.php" method="post">
<ul>
<li>DishID: <input type="text" name="DishID"></li>
<li>Name: <input type="text" name="DishName"></li>
<li>Catagory : <input type="text" name="DishCatID"></li>
<li>Serving: <input type="text" name="Serving"></li>
<li>SRP: <input type="text" name="SRP"></li>
<li>Method : <input type="text" name="Method"></li>
<li>Source : <input type="text" name="SourceID"></li>
<br>
<li>IngID: <input type="text" name="IngID[]"></li>
<li>Volume: <input type="text" name="Volume[]"></li>

<li>IngID: <input type="text" name="IngID[]"></li>
<li>Volume: <input type="text" name="Volume[]"></li>

<li>IngID: <input type="text" name="IngID[]"></li>
<li>Volume: <input type="text" name="Volume[]"></li>

</ul>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then your PHP should be:

```
$DishID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['DishID']);
$DishName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['DishName']);
$DishCatID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['DishCatID']);
$Serving = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Serving']);
$SRP = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['SRP']);
$Method = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Method']);
$SourceID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['SourceID']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Dishes (DishID, DishName, DishCatID, Serving, SRP, Method, SourceID)
      VALUES ('$DishID', '$DishName', '$DishCatID', '$Serving', '$SRP', '$Method', '$SourceID')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$values = array();
foreach ($_POST['IngID'] as $i => $ingID) {
    if (!empty($ingID)) {
        $ingID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ingID);
        $volume = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Volume'][$i]);
        $values[] = "('$DishID', '$ingID', '$volume')";
    }
}
if (!empty($values)) {
    $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO DishIng (DishID, IngID, Volume) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $values);
    mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your `$sql2`, the first row you add inside your `foreach` loop is not separated by a comma. It also does not have the same number of fields (3 and 2).

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO DishIng (DishID, IngID, Volume) VALUES ('$DishID', '$IngID', '$Volume')"; // 3 fields
...
$sql2 .= "('".$cit->key()."','" .$cit->current()."')"; // 2 fields
```

A good way to do this is to store your strings inside an array and use `implode` function with `','` as glue. A comma will be inserted automaticaly between two elements.

Comment: Sorry to be thick here, but where would I put the extra comma?  I took this method from a tutorial, so not sure I've fully understood it.

Comment: It depends. If you have multiple fields, you must add one after `'$Volume')`. But not if you have only one value. This is why it is better to insert all your `('$DishID', '$IngID', '$Volume')` inside an array and use `$sql2 = implode(',', $array);`

Comment: How would you specify the table it goes into?

Do you mean like this?
    '$array = array('$DishID', '$IngID', '$Volume');
    $sql2 = implode(',', $array);'

The DishID would always be the same for each row.  The other two would be variable.  There could be many lines of these.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the created Query.

There is a comma missing between your static sql2-string and the dynamic values. Also the values you want to insert are not correct I assume. With the query you create you want to insert 4 Lines and you'Re using dishID, IngID and Volume as IngID in your request what you don't want I think.

P.S.: You can use tools like MySQL Workbench to test your statements before implementing them. (And you can see their results)

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow where you're saying the comma is missing.

I want DishID to always remain the same in the second SQL table from the first SQL statement.  The second statement should just update the variable ingredients and volumes into another table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example for adding row dynamically using javascript, if you consider using table:

```
<div>
<input name='buttonadd' type='button' id='add_table' value='Add'>
</div>

<table id='mytable'>
    <tr>
    <td>DishID: <input type="text" name="DishID[]"></td>
    <td>Name: <input type="text" name="DishName[]"></td>
    <td>Catagory : <input type="text" name="DishCatID[]"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

and here's the javascript:

```
$("#add_table").click(function(){
 $('#mytable tr').last().after('<tr><td>DishID: <input type="text" name="DishID[]"></td><td>Name: <input type="text" name="DishName[]"></td><td>Catagory : <input type="text" name="DishCatID[]"></td>
        </tr>');
 });
```